# how to find who deleted data from Front End (Infor WM app) DB (oracle 11g)

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

this is something critical for me. In the last few days some data from one table is deleted (Oracle 11g).
I have checked with DBA but in the database, nothing is logged and he said that data is deleted from the front end.
Can anyone help me to find out what data is deleted and who did it as neither application's logs are having any information and Audit_trial in DB is set to none?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using LogMiner. This is a built-in utility of oracle that scans redo-logs/archived-logs and displays all DML commands that were run.

Comment: Thanks, Michael for responding, I will check the same with DBA.